# jpql delete query is active since long time

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

jpql delete query is active for last 4 hours. When I tried to execute the same query directly on the database console it took around 30seconds to execute.The total data to delete is maximum 100000. I have index on id. I am unable to understand. Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks

```
@Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM IoEntity WHERE Id = :id")
    void deleteAllById(@Param("id") UUID id);
```

Comment: Is there a pending "commit" in your database? To check, just do a commit in  your database console.

Comment: Maybe the table is continusly blocked by other proceses. Try to isolate the database before run the query to check it.

Comment: @RiyaGeorge: yes it was not committed somehow. can we make sure somehow that it gets committed all the time using jpa?

Comment: @JosemyAB: no it was not blocked by any other process. but it was blocking other queries to run as delete creates lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you run a DML in your DB using SQL clients like Toad, SQL Developer etc, make sure you commit it unless auto commit is turned on in the client.

If you are doing the delete via JPA, commit will be taken care by Spring when you define @Transactional in your service method.

Comment: @RiyaGeorge still facing same issue and i have added @ Transactional to my service method.

Comment: @WitWikky Did you check if any uncommitted statements that you ran directly on the DB?